# change (CurlCode, String) to String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a simple haskell program which GETs a JSON string from a webserver and parses it.

I am using the curlGetString method of Network.Curl.

This method has the following type signature

```
curlGetString :: URLString -> [CurlOption] -> IO (CurlCode, String)
```

My question is: How do I convert the output from (CurlCode, String) to String?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response body is just the second element of the tuple. First bind the result of `curlGetString` in the `IO` monad, then use [`snd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asnd), or better, pattern matching:

```
main = do
  (code, body) <- curlGetString "http://foo.example.com/" [...]
  case code of
    CurlOK -> putStr body
    _ -> putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ show code
```

Don’t forget that you can find functions by type with [a Hoogle search](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%2C+b%29+-%3E+b).

Comment: Thanks! For the life of me, I didn't recognize that the type signature contained a tuple.